# Form Closing with DialogResult

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `Form1` that has a button on it. When the button is clicked `Form2` will open up.

The new form that pops up asks the user to enter in data to save to a file and when the `Form2`'s button is clicked it saves the entered user data to a specified path.

Here is the `Form2`'s button click code:

```
private void dataBaseSaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (firstNameTextBox.Text.Equals(string.Empty) || lastNameTextBox.Text.Equals(string.Empty) || payTextBox.Text.Equals(string.Empty))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill out all of the fields.", "Fields Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

        else
        {
            //This is where I am saving the data to a file using StreamWrriter.

            this.Close();
        }
```

So now that `Form2` has closed a new `Form2` will open up, etc, etc.. (There is a loop in `Form1` that does this).

### My problem is...

In `Form2` I also have a `_FormClosed` event that looks like this:

```
private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult userAnswer = MessageBox.Show ("Do you wish to close ALL " + counterLabel.Text + " of the 'Form2' forms?", "Close ALL Forms?", 
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (userAnswer == DialogResult.Yes)
            this.Dispose();
    }
```

### So my question is...

How do I call the button click to properly close the `Form2` **WITHOUT** calling the `_FormClosed` event while keeping the functionality of the forms the same?

### EDIT:

I know `this.Hide();` will do the trick.. but I am wondering if there is a way to not hide all of the `Form2`'s since there could be a large amount..

Comment: @Smelch: The problem is the `MessageBox` is showing up when I click the "dataBaseSaveButton` and I don't want it to. I only want the `MessageBox` to show up when I click on the ***"X"*** in the upper right hand corner of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid FormClosed being called but you can add some logic to ignore it.

e.g. set a flag when you are force closing the form (something like `bool _forceClose`) and check for that flag in your `FormClosed` event. If it is set, then just return and ignore the rest of the statements.

Comment: So something like changing the code in the event to.. `if (userAnswer == DialogResult.Yes && _forceClose == false)`?

Comment: that would be fine if you want to still show the message box to the user, if you want to close silently, just add `if (_forceClose) return` at the very beginning of the method (and set the appropiate DialogResult)

Answer (score 3):

I think your application has an odd behaviour.  Usually when a user enters rows of data it is performed in some kind of grid.
But to answer your question you should remove the event handling:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.FormClosed -= Form_Closed;
    this.Close();
}
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you need to change your closing event to determine if you need to cancel it or not:

Based on your comment, you would have to set a local variable as a flag.  The `CloseReason` property in the `FormClosedEventArgs` will be set to `UserClosing` with either method of closing the form (despite what the documentation says).

```
private bool _ConfirmClosing = true;

private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
  if (_ConfirmClosing) {
    DialogResult userAnswer = MessageBox.Show ("Do you wish to close ALL " + counterLabel.Text + " of the 'Form2' forms?", "Close ALL Forms?", 
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    if (userAnswer == DialogResult.No)
      e.Cancel = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just introduce a new public form property to hold the boolean value if you form can be closed or not:

```
public boolean CanClose { get; set; }
```

then in your constructor set this value to `false`:

```
public Form2()
{
   //....
   CanClose = false;
}
```

Upon saving your data just set this property to `true`:

```
private void dataBaseSaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (firstNameTextBox.Text.Equals(string.Empty) || lastNameTextBox.Text.Equals(string.Empty) || payTextBox.Text.Equals(string.Empty))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill out all of the fields.", "Fields Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

        else
        {
            //This is where I am saving the data to a file using StreamWrriter.

            CanClose = true;

            this.Close();
        }
```

and, finally, in your closing event just check whether you can close the form silently or you need to show a dialogue:

```
private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (!CanClose) 
      {
         DialogResult userAnswer = MessageBox.Show ("Do you wish to close ALL " + counterLabel.Text + " of the 'Form2' forms?", "Close ALL Forms?", 
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
         if (userAnswer != DialogResult.Yes) 
         {
           e.Cancel = true;
           return;
         }
      }

       this.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Windows.Forms library is usually inconsistent when it comes to events being fired or not when actions are called programmatically.

I would suggest that you keep a member in your form to know whether or not you want to ignore the event.

```
private void dataBaseSaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (firstNameTextBox.Text.Equals(string.Empty) || lastNameTextBox.Text.Equals(string.Empty) || payTextBox.Text.Equals(string.Empty))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill out all of the fields.", "Fields Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }

    else
    {
        //This is where I am saving the data to a file using StreamWrriter.
        this.IgnoreCloseEvent = true;

        this.Close();

        this.IgnoreCloseEvent = false;
    }
```

And then

```
private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IgnoreCloseEvent)
         return

    DialogResult userAnswer = MessageBox.Show ("Do you wish to close ALL " + counterLabel.Text + " of the 'Form2' forms?", "Close ALL Forms?", 
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    if (userAnswer == DialogResult.Yes)
        this.Dispose();
}
```

It's a pain to have to do this all the time, but for me, it has always worked better than trying to figure out what the Windows.Forms library was doing.